# options("devtools.desc.author") doesn't stick,

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools

I'd like the `devtools` package to remember my name, email and other preferences for creating packages. I used the following code to change the options

```
options(devtools.desc.author = person(given = "charm", family = "goggles", email = "my@email.com", role = c("cre","aut")))
```

And when I check the options with

`options("devtools.desc.author")` the setting have indeed changed. 
However when I open a new project in Rstudio the settings are back to the standard settings

```
options("devtools.desc.author")
$devtools.desc.author
[1] "person(\"First\", \"Last\", email = \"first.last@example.com\", role = c(\"aut\", \"cre\"))"
```

How can I make these general options so that they remain in all my projects?

Comment: You're missing an "=" in the first options. `author=person`

Comment: yes, thanks! I will edit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to csgillespie

This would be the final answer:

Opening the profile with

`file.edit("~/.Rprofile")`

and I wrote this in the file:

`options(devtools.desc.author = utils::person(given = "charm", family = "goggles", email = "my@email.com", role = c("cre","aut")))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to store this information in you `.Rprofile`. You `.Rprofile` is just an R script that is read at start-up. See `?.Rprofile`.

You can either create one per RStudio project, or just put one in your home area. I suspect you don't have one, so just run

```
file.edit("~/.Rprofile")
```

To create and open the file.

Comment: Thanks cs gillespie! Indeed this was not created yet, however I now get the following error in every session: 
```
Error in options(devtools.desc.author = person(given = "charm", family = "goggles" : 
  could not find function "person"
```
Is this because these are devtools options?

Comment: The `utils` package has been loaded when Rprofile is read in, so it can't find the `person` function. Try `utils::person` instead